# Search a textfile using elements from a dictionary or other data structure in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to read in a text file and using a dictionary to see if certain words or other characters appear in the text file. If so how many?

Here is my code so far:

```
d = {}        
d["keyword"] = ["he","him","his"]
print d
keywords = 0
print ("Opening the file")
with open('textFile.txt','r') as foo:
    for line in foo:
        elements = line.split()
        for d["keyword"] in elements:
            if d["keyword"] in line:
                keywords +=1

print keywords
```

the output I want is to print out how many of the keywords were in the file. Right now I'm getting how many totals words there are in my text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run `for d["keyword"] in elements`, you will change the content of `d["keyword"]` to the current word in `elements`.

I think it should be:

```
for line in foo:
    elements = line.split()
    for elem in elements:
        if elem in d["keyword"]:
            keywords +=1
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you very much for the explanation it helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1.If we do not use the Dict.then then we can use..

```
    d= ["he","him","his"]
    print d
    keywords = 0
    print ("Opening the file")
    with open('textFile.txt','r') as foo:
    for line in foo:
        elements = line.split()
        print elements
        for i in range(len(d)):
            for jj in range(len(elements)):
                if d[i] == elements[jj]:
                    print d[i]
                    keywords +=1
   print keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for line in foo:
    elements = list(line.split())
    for element in elements:
         if element in d["keyword"]:
               keywords +=1 
print keywords
```